# checking C LLVM Bitcode compiler works... /xxx/llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-dis: Invalid type for value

Tags: linux, ubuntu, llvm, klee

This error appears when I try to install LLVM 3.4 before [installing Klee](http://klee.github.io/build-llvm34/).

The sources code is downloaded from LLVM official website and decompressed to a separate file from Klee. Makefile in llvm-3.4 directory is used to build LLVM.

To build Klee, first:

```
./configure --with-llvm=/home/zhangysh1995/work/llvm-3.4/ --wi
th-stp=/home/zhangysh1995/work/stp/stp
```

And the error:

```
....
checking for clang... FOUND
checking for clang++... FOUND
Using C llvm compiler : /usr/bin/clang
Using C++ llvm compiler : /usr/bin/clang++
checking C LLVM Bitcode compiler works... 
/home/zhangysh1995/work/llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-dis: In
valid type for value
configure: error: Failed converting LLVM Bitcode to LLVM assembly. Maybe your LLVM versions do not match?
```

It seems this error is thrown from Klee but there is no problem with my LLVM version as Klee guide says.

Another similar problem was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337845/klee-configuration-error) and [here](http://mailman.ic.ac.uk/pipermail/klee-dev/2014-February/000597.html), but not helpful.

I still have no idea where to start my debug. I appreciate any possible help.

Comment: Please  leave comments if you have any idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means klee use `/usr/bin/clang++` to compile example souce code to .bc . And then use `/home/zhangysh1995/work/llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-dis` to disassamble it.

You can verify the version missmatch by comparing the output of `$ /usr/bin/clang++ --version` and `$ /home/zhangysh1995/work/llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ --version`.

To solve this, please use:

```
 ./configure \
 --with-llvm=/home/zhangysh1995/work/llvm-3.4/ \
 --with-llvmcc=/home/zhangysh1995/work/llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/bin/clang \
 --with-llvmcxx=/home/zhangysh1995/work/llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ \
 --with-stp=/home/zhangysh1995/work/stp/stp
```